# ExecuteMso - Change Picture > From a File

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I would like to create a button that would bring up the change picture feature in excel.  I want the users to be able to click the button above the pictures to change the pictures when needed.

Can someone give me some insight on why this macro doesn't work?

```
Sub ChangePicture()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("PIC_RENTCOMP1A")).Select
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PictureChange")
End Sub
```

I want to have the same feature as Right Click > Change Picture > From a File...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" is there anything happening at all?

Comment: What does the Macro Recorder code look like? You're simply selecting an image here as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Albin I am getting an error that says "Method 'ExecuteMso' of object '_CommandBars' failed" with "Run-time error '-2147467259 (800040005)'"

Comment: Quite late to answer but, instead of "PictureChange", try "PictureChangeFromFile" for older version